# Is it possible to import altium libraries all at once

Tags: components, altium, library, setup, project-management

I am trying to setup my own library folder without using the altium 365 or the vault feature. Is there a way I can install all the intlib/pcblibs+schlib all at once or make it part of a project template? Without needing to go through every folder and installing it manually every time

Answer (score 0):

If you have alitum 20, then yes. Just create a design workspace (.dsnwrk) and then you should be able to import or create pcb project files (.prjpcb files). You can either add the libs into the project or through tools->preferences->data management->installed libraries

Comment: Well i am using 21, but when i add it through data management it is still one by one or if i use the search path it doesn't show any results. Do you maybe know how to fix that?

Comment: If you make it part of a project, you should be able to drag the files into the project window.

Comment: Works in all (~10 years anyway) versions of Altium.  Not new for AD20+.

Comment: And AD20 is pretty much AD21 in form and function anyway. I still run AD17 mostly, the UI is much easier to use and has better features